# custom Scroll-Bar on a div element in Angular 2.0 CLI project?

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, scrollbar, angular2-directives

I want to make a nice horizontal scroll bar in one of my div's. Like this ones here:
[image]

I'm using angular2 CLI project.

**What I've tried so far:** 
I found this package [angular2-slimscroll](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-slimscroll) - the latest updated one is [here](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-slimscroll): - but is not working as expected - i guess it has to do with the final angular 2.0 final release which broke the code.

```
npm install ng2-slimscroll --save
```

In my ***app.module.ts*** i have:

```
import {SlimScroll} from 'ng2-slimscroll';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SlimScroll // added as a directive
    ]
    ....
})
```

Than in the ***scrollable.component.ts*** i do:

```
import {SlimScroll} from 'ng2-slimscroll';
Import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     templateUrl: '
        <div class="my-scrollable-div" 
             slimscroll                      // the directive doesn't work.
             background="#333" 
             opacity="0.6" 
             position="right" 
             width="7px"> 

             Div Content is empty !! I don't know how to use this i guess:)

        </div>',
     styleUrls: ['./my-app.component.css']
})
```

**Questions:**

Any ideas why this SlimScroll package is not working?

Other solutions ? What are you guys using for this job? (angular2 related)

Just to clarify. I'm not fixated on this package. Any implementation will do for now. But i think is better to use a package - instead of trying to implement myself a cross browser compatibility thing for this custom scroll.

Thank's so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
Import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `
        <div slimscroll
             background="#333" 
             opacity="0.6" 
             position="right" 
             width="7px" 
             border-radius="5px"
             style="margin: 0px 0px; width: 600px; height: 250px;">
             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1. 10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Where can I get some?
        </div>
     `,
     styleUrls: ['./my-app.component.css']
})
```

Good luck!

Comment: There are errors in your template markup (extra `>`). How does this help?

Answer (score 1):

You have `slimscroll` on your `div`. It should be `slimScroll`.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try ngx-scrollbar from [here](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-scrollbar). Works fine in Angular 4+